# How to make a debian package from ubuntu SDK?

Tags: 14.04, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I have created an App using the Ubuntu SDK and now I can't find a way to package it. 
The documentation says the easiest way to do so is using the publish button located on the left bar in ubuntu SDK, but in my case it is greyed out.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debian packaging feature is not available for qt creator , If you are intersted , you can create a qt creator plugin for that . currently ubuntu plugin for qtcreator support click packaging , but it is available for qml apps only :-)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up packaging the app manually. Although I think a plugin would make it lot easier.